# java.lang.RuntimeException Error, Cannot figure out why

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I'm getting a java.lang.RuntimeException Error in logcat for my app. It then goes on to show the error is coming from:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        gps = new GPSTracker(EditProductActivity.this);
        double inputlat = gps.getLatitude();
        double inputlong = gps.getLongitude();

        String inputLat=Double.toString(inputlat);
        String inputLong=Double.toString(inputlong);

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String longitude = inputLong;
        String latitude = inputLat;

        Log.d("Get this far?", pid);//something wrong with these when I want to save
        String pavement = spinpavement.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String traffic = spintraffic.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String environment = spinenviro.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Oh no something is wrong here
        // Building Parameters

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LONG, longitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LAT, latitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PAVEMENT, pavement));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TRAFFIC, traffic));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ENVIRONMENT, environment));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                //Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                //setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see the error comes at:

```
String pavement = spinpavement.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String traffic = spintraffic.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String environment = spinenviro.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But I can not figure out what is wrong with it.

Here is the whole logcat from where the error starts

```
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 24403
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$SaveProductDetails.doInBackground(EditProductActivity.java:225)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$SaveProductDetails.doInBackground(EditProductActivity.java:1)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-16 19:20:29.446: E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    ... 3 more
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{421bbd78 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at  android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$SaveProductDetails.onPreExecute(EditProductActivity.java:202)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity.onClick(EditProductActivity.java:87)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3837)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18498)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-16 19:20:30.019: E/WindowManager(24403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Exactly which line is 225? If its one of the lines that you posted then show how/where you initialized `spinpavement` and those other variables which I'm guessing are `Spinners`

Comment: Yup that is the line and yes they are Spinners

Comment: Ok, but where/how are you initializing them? Can you post that because they must be `null`. Either that or `getSelectedItem()` `returns null`

Comment: Yup that would be the problem haha thanks I guess I must have erased the initializing lines. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first line corresponds to line 225, then the NullPointerException is maybe because there is nothing selected int the spinner. Try:

```
String pavement = (spinpavement!=null)?String.valueOf(spinpavement.getSelectedItem()):"NULL Pavement";
String traffic = (spintraffic!=null)?String.valueOf(spintraffic.getSelectedItem()):"NULL Traffic";
String environment = (spinenviro!=null)?String.valueOf(spinenviro.getSelectedItem()):"NULL Environment";
```

and you'll be able to realize if there's some issue or lost reference to any of your member variables.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

check it..before getting selected string..

```
if(spinner.getselectedpostion!=0)
{`
`
String selected_string= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

}`enter code here`
```